# VS Code DevTools Dark Theme has black console text on dark backgrounds

Tags: electron, google-chrome-devtools, visual-studio-code

I switched the Chrome/Electron DevTools *Theme* to *Dark* (in the DevTools Settings, under *Preferences*), so that it doesn't glare late at night.

But the console text is rendered black still, which is difficult to read on the dark backgrounds for *Errors* or *Warnings*:

[image]

Is there a setting for the DevTools themselves that I should look into, or is this an Issue I should raise in [VS Code](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md)? Or [Electron](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md)?

Comment: It's definitely an issue as I was able to replicate this as well. I was not able to find any setting that can help change this behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unsure when, but it's been fixed.  Here is Code 1.42

[image: VSCode 1.42 in Dark Theme, with Developer Tools embedded to the right, shows error text with light text on dark background]

Thank you.